# Breadth First Search (rush hour) - Linked list queue contains duplicates of the same board

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

Hello stackoverflow users,
I am attempting to implement a breadth first search on the classic rush hour game. However, I am having a problem with the queue. Before I add something to the queue, I printed out what each board looks like:

```
[-, 0, 0, -, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 4, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, -]
[5, -, -, -, 6, 6]
[5, -, 7, 7, 7, -]

0 1 0
[-, -, 0, 0, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 4, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, -]
[5, -, -, -, 6, 6]
[5, -, 7, 7, 7, -]

0 2 0
[-, -, -, 0, 0, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 4, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, -]
[5, -, -, -, 6, 6]
[5, -, 7, 7, 7, -]
```

However, when I print out the queue, it comes out like this:

```
[-, -, 0, 0, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 4, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, -]
[5, -, -, -, 6, 6]
[5, -, 7, 7, 7, -]

[-, -, -, 0, 0, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 4, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, -]
[5, -, -, -, 6, 6]
[5, -, 7, 7, 7, -]

[-, -, -, 0, 0, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, 1]
[2, 3, 3, 4, -, 1]
[2, -, -, 4, -, -]
[5, -, -, -, 6, 6]
[5, -, 7, 7, 7, -]
```

The segment of code which I printed out these boards:

```
for (int i = car.getY() + 1; i < (5 - car.getLen()) + 1; i++) {
    if (isSafeHorizontal(b, car, i)) {
        Board copy = new Board(b.boardVehicles, b.moves, nextCar);
        copy.moveVehicle(car.getX(), i, b.currentCar);
        for (int a = 0;  a< queue.size(); a++) {
            System.out.println(queue.get(a));
        }

        //System.out.println(copy);System.out.println("" + car.getX() + " " + i + " " + b.currentCar);
        queue.add(copy);
    }
}
```

I thought there might be a problem with references, but I could not come up with any reasons why it should not be working.

edit:
Here's my entire code for reference:
[BreadthFirstSearch.java](http://pastebin.com/Hjv19jf2), [Board.java AND Vehicle.java](http://pastebin.com/DPXrfGQ6)

Comment: What is queue? How is it created?

Comment: Queue is a linked list of Board objects, consisting of vehicle objects.

Comment: It seems like your Board objects or your vehicle Objects are not being created properly. There isn't really enough code here to determine where the problem is.

Comment: I thought so too, but I went over my Board.java and could not find the source of my problem. I have also included a pastebin of my 3 classes for reference.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem, but in your Board constructor, you don't need to iterate over the ArrayList and the Array, you can just assign them to moves and boardVehicles

Comment: If I do that wouldn't it have references to the string and vehicles instead of copying a new one?

Comment: the moves class ArrayList moves will reference the ArrayList moves that was passed into the constructor. Same with the Vehicles Array.

Comment: So your problem is that when you print out the boards how they should be they print 1->2->3->4, but when you print out what your boards actually are, they print 2->3->4->5? And the first board isn't printing?

Comment: So after the first run of the algorithm, there should be 3 nodes in the queue that should look like the first boards I pasted. However, when I print the queue out, it has a board with the 0 vehicle on (2,0) and (3,0). It should not be like this, instead it should have the 0 vehicle on (1,0), (2,0) (3,0) like the boards printed on the very top. I thought it might be a problem with the references, but as this is my first time using linked lists I am not very familiar with how they work. The way I tried to identify the problem is this:

Comment: I printed out each node (or board) right before I added it to the queue and they were perfect, as demonstrated in the first three nodes I posted. However, after adding them to the queue, it appeared like the boards in the second example. I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem looks two fold:

1. You are missing the first node (or board) when you print out the list the second time.
2. You are printing the third item twice.

The solution for one: Is seen at line 94 in your BreadthFirstSearch class in the pastebin:

```
System.out.println(firstNode);
            LinkedList<Board> queue = new LinkedList<Board>();
            queue.addFirst(firstNode);
            Board solved = null;
            while (queue.size() != 0) {
                    Board b = queue.get(0);

                    System.out.println("!===========\ns: " + queue.size() + "\n");
                    //for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); i++){System.out.println(queue.get(i));}
                    queue.remove(0);
```

You are retrieving the first item, and then you remove it. So you are missing the first item. I don't think there is any reason for you to remove that node.

The solution for problem number 2:

It looks like you are adding a node with the same information twice in the if statement between lines 110 - 133:

```
 if (car.getDir().equals("V")) {
     // go through every position before the current car's X
     for (int i = 0; ((i < car.getX()) && (i < (5 - car.getLen()) + 1)); i++) {
         // no car in current position? create new vehicle
         // instance
         if (isSafeVertical(b, car, i)) {
             Board copy = new Board(b.boardVehicles, b.moves, nextCar);
             copy.moveVehicle(i, car.getY(), b.currentCar);
             queue.add(copy);
         }
     }
     // go through every position after current car's x
     for (int i = car.getX() + 1; i < (5 - car.getLen()) + 1; i++) {
         // no car in current pos? create new vehicle instance.
             if (isSafeVertical(b, car, i)) {
                 Board copy = new Board(b.boardVehicles, b.moves, nextCar);
                 copy.moveVehicle(i, car.getY(), b.currentCar);
                 queue.add(copy);
             }
     }
     // move horizontal cars and add to queue
```

Look at how you are adding the nodes there and look at how you are adding nodes to the queue in the for statement that prints out the nodes.